# How to show search result using form in another page

Tags: php, html, forms

When user search his mobile no. or id in search form then his all data (Credit History, Personal Details) show on homepage.php

But homepage consists credit history and personal details on same place. and the credit history has multiple records as like our bank passbook.

Now I want  that when user click on a LINK mention on homepage it will forward all credit history to a new page link1.php which show only credit history.

I successfully able to forward a credit history on new page link1.php using $_session but i am not able to forward all credit records searched using search form on homepage.

Eg. When user search his mobile no. 3333
on 1-form.php it will redirect user to homepage.php with his personal details(Name,Mobile etc)
and Credit history has multiple records (like or bank passbook has multiple credit entrees)

in the homepage user see a link which redirect user to link1.php where he only check his credit history already fetched in homepage.php
.
but when user clink on the link he only see single record last entry in link1.php
he want to see all his history on link1.php using session or any other method.

My configuration is below.
**1-form.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- (A) SEARCH FORM -->
    <form method="post" action="homepage.php">
      <h1>SEARCH FOR USERS</h1>
      <input type="text" name="username" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    <table>
```

**2-search.php**

```
<?php
// (A) DATABASE CONFIG - CHANGE TO YOUR OWN!
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "test2");
define("DB_CHARSET", "utf8");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");

// (B) CONNECT TO DATABASE
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHARSET.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
                    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 
                    [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                     PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
                    ]
            );
} catch (Exception $ex) { 
    exit($ex->getMessage()); 
}

// (C) SEARCH
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * 
                        FROM `table1` 
                        WHERE `Id` LIKE ? 
                        OR `Mobile` LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%".$_POST["username"]."%", 
                "%".$_POST["username"]."%"]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST["ajax"])) { 
    echo json_encode($results); 
}
$pdo->connection = null;
$pdo=null;

try {
    $pdo2 = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHARSET.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
                    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,
                    [
                      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
                    ]
            );
} catch (Exception $ex) { 
    exit($ex->getMessage()); 
}

// (C) SEARCH
$stmt2 = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT * 
                        FROM `table2` 
                        WHERE `Id` LIKE ? 
                        OR `Paymobile` LIKE ?");
$stmt2->execute(["%".$_POST["username"]."%", 
                "%".$_POST["username"]."%"]);
$results2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST["ajax"])) { 
    echo json_encode($results2); 
}

$pdo2->connection = null;
$pdo2=null;
```

**homepage.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php
// (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS 
?>
<div class="card-body p-0">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
    </div>
<?php
// (B) PROCESS SEARCH WHEN FORM SUBMITTED
if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
    // (B1) SEARCH FOR USERS
    require "2-search.php";
?>
<?php
      // (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS
    if (count($results) > 0) { 
        foreach ($results as $r) {
?>  
                                            
                    <td><?php echo $r['Name'] ;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['Mobile'] ;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['Email'] ;?></td> 
                </tr>
<?php
        }
    } else { 
        echo "No results found"; 
    }
}
?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="card-body p-0">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
        </div>
<?php
// (B) PROCESS SEARCH WHEN FORM SUBMITTED
if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
    // (B1) SEARCH FOR USERS
?>
<?php
    // (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS
    if (count($results2) > 0) { 
        foreach ($results2 as $r2) {
?>  
                                            
                    <td><?php echo $r2['Month'] ;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r2['Amount'] ;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r2['Date'] ;?></td> 
                </tr>
<?php
        }
    } else { 
        echo "No results found"; 
    }
}
?>
<?php
$_SESSION['r2m'] = $r2['Month'];
$_SESSION['r2a'] = $r2['Amount'];
$_SESSION['r2d'] = $r2['Date'];
?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <a href="link1.php">Click here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</table>
</html>
```

**link1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>                  
            <td><?php echo $_SESSION['r2m'] ;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_SESSION['r2a'] ;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_SESSION['r2d'] ;?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: A few things here. 1. Your `$_SESSION['r2m'] = $r2['Month'];` should be inside the foreach or it will only use the last value (or throw error for undefined variable `$r2` if you don't get any result). 2. They should also be `$_SESSION['r2m'][] = $r2['Month'];` (you need to push it to an array or you'll just overwrite the value). However, I would just pass the search string in the URL (query string) to link1.php and fetch the result from DB again.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: If you want to stick with sessions, then you can simply store the result: `$_SESSION['results'] = $results;` and then iterate through it on link1.php, just like you do on `homepage.php`

Comment: _Big Note_ One script only need to connect to the database ONCE not every time you want to run a new query

Comment: i don't know to much about foreach. Although when i try to do it using your 2nd answer $_SESSION['results'] = $results; then it will show single record last time inserted value.

Comment: Can you please provide me how to does foreach script work in $_SESSION so that it can fetch all records.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have used Multiple query because i have multiple database this is not a problem. The main problem here is i not able to fetch all records in my another page. In my homepage all records are fetched but when user click on link1 it show only last value.

Comment: @M.Eriksson the problem as been solved with your help. Thankyou now my new configuration is below as you suggest. but still i have a little problem when i press back button on link1.php to go back then it will forget my all  pervious records and show error Confirm Form Resubmission. ERR_CACHE_MISS

Answer (score -1):

My New configuration But it has one problem one user press back button to go back on homepage.php it will not redirect him back to homepage.php It simply close the session like ( some net banking sites warning us to don't press back button
otherwise we have to login again) when user click back button it show error.

*Confirm Form ResubmissionThis webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
ERR_CACHE_MISS*

**1-form.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- (A) SEARCH FORM -->
    <form method="post" action="homepage.php">
      <h1>SEARCH FOR USERS</h1>
      <input type="text" name="username" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    <table>
```

**2-search.php**

```
<?php
// (A) DATABASE CONFIG - CHANGE TO YOUR OWN!
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "test2");
define("DB_CHARSET", "utf8");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");

// (B) CONNECT TO DATABASE
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHARSET.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ]
  );
} catch (Exception $ex) { exit($ex->getMessage()); }

// (C) SEARCH
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `Id` LIKE ? OR `Mobile` LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%".$_POST["username"]."%", "%".$_POST["username"]."%"]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST["ajax"])) { echo json_encode($results); }

$pdo->connection = null;
$pdo=null;




try {
  $pdo2 = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHARSET.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ]
  );
} catch (Exception $ex) { exit($ex->getMessage()); }

// (C) SEARCH
$stmt2 = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `Id` LIKE ? OR `Paymobile` LIKE ?");
$stmt2->execute(["%".$_POST["username"]."%", "%".$_POST["username"]."%"]);
$results2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST["ajax"])) { echo json_encode($results2); }

$pdo2->connection = null;
$pdo2=null;
```

**homepage.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
?>

<?php
// (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS 
?>
 <div class="card-body p-0">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Mobile</th>
                                        <th>Email</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                    
                                            
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
    // (B) PROCESS SEARCH WHEN FORM SUBMITTED
    if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
      // (B1) SEARCH FOR USERS
      require "2-search.php";
      ?>
      <?php
      // (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS
      if (count($results) > 0) { foreach ($results as $r) {
      ?>  
                                            
                                                    <td><?php echo $r['Name'] ;?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $r['Mobile'] ;?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $r['Email'] ;?></td> 
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
      }} else { echo "No results found"; }
    }
    ?>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


<div class="card-body p-0">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Mobile</th>
                                        <th>Email</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                    
                                            
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
    // (B) PROCESS SEARCH WHEN FORM SUBMITTED
    if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
      // (B1) SEARCH FOR USERS
      
      ?>
      <?php
      // (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS
      if (count($results2) > 0) { foreach ($results2 as $r2) {
      ?>  
                                        <?php
                                            $_SESSION['r2m'] = $r2
                                            
                                            ?>
                                                    <td><?php echo $r2['Month'] ;?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $r2['Amount'] ;?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $r2['Date'] ;?></td> 
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
      }} else { echo "No results found"; }
    }
    ?>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <a href="link1.php">Click here</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</table>
</html>
```

**link1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php
        $_POST['username'] = $_SESSION['username'];
                                     ?>       
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
    // (B) PROCESS SEARCH WHEN FORM SUBMITTED
    if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
      // (B1) SEARCH FOR USERS
      require "2-search.php";
      ?>
      <?php
      // (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS
      if (count($results2) > 0) { foreach ($results2 as $r2) {
      ?>  
                                            
                                                    <td><?php echo $r2['Month'] ;?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $r2['Amount'] ;?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $r2['Date'] ;?></td> 
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
      }} else { echo "No results found"; }
    }
    ?>

       
     
</table>
```

Comment: This is a completely different issue and should be posted as another question, not as an answer to your previous question. But in short, the browser needs to make a POST request to that page to be able to recreate it, or `$_POST['username']` wouldn't be defined. I would change the search for to `<form method="get"` instead and then use `$_GET['username']`. Problem solved. You are _GETting_ data, after all. POST is usually for sending data to the server to be stored (which is why the browser asks if you really want to resubmit the data again since it could cause duplicates etc)

Comment: @M.Eriksson Thankyou i will try with Get method once  and now as you say this is another question not related to this then i end up this question as Problem solved. Thanks a lot.